# cannot patch game because of lack of admin privliges

Tags: windows-7, download, administrator, winzip

i download the patch, which is zipped, but when i tell winzip to extract it to the file location, i get this error message saying i need admin privileges. i should have these to begin with, have tried creating new admin profile and various other things, no dice. also had the a similar problem with non-zipped version, installshield error 1628

"Extracting to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Midway Home Entertainment\"
Use Path: yes   Overlay Files: no
Error: Access is denied.
Cannot create C:\Program Files (x86)\Midway Home Entertainment\suffering.exe; administrative privileges may be required
Severe Error: File creation failed.

Error code:  0
Error description: "

Answer (score -1):

Run WinZip as administrator. To do that, find a shortcut to WinZip on the desktop or in the start menu, right-click on it and select Run as administrator. Then navigate to the archive and extract it.

If that doesn't work, try extracting the files to a safe folder, such as My Documents, then moving them to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Midway Home Entertainment\` in Explorer. Windows will ask you to confirm the move.

The issue here is that Windows only lets programs with admin privileges make changes to the Program Files folder.

Comment: thank you, this still did not solve the 1628 error, but it got winzip to work, which was enough to solve the problem